# How I Implement CopyTo?

Tags: c#

I wonder if I can implement CopyTo in ICollection. It stated that it doesn't use ref keyword. I have tried this, but it don't compile

```
    public void CopyTo(ref KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] destination, int start)
    {
        pairs.CopyTo(destination, start);
    }
```

It said:

> Error 4   'Cyan.Collection.WatchableDictionary' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection>.CopyTo(System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[], int)'   D:\CE\Supins\Cyan Pembuat Soal\Required Manipulation\ObservableDictionary.cs    15  18  Required Manipulation

But if I remove ref keyword, I'm afraid if it can't longer behave like normal in other ICollection-Implemented class.(Actually, I am building a dictionary)

Any help will apreciated.

<strike>Don't be confused if the error is in namespace System.Collection. I design my code in that namespace.</strike> I has just moved the namespace from System.Collection to Cyan.Collection.

Comment: Why in the world are you putting your own code in the `System` namespace?

Comment: "*I design my code in that namespace*" - have you read the [namespace guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618(v=vs.71).aspx)?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking the interface and choosing implement interface? ( I agree with above comments)

Comment: Why don't you let VS help you? Right click on the interface and choose *Implement interface*

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken: Maybe the company is called *System* :-)

Comment: No, I don't have company, But the System.Collection is for collection and so does it.

Comment: And I think its for global use.

Comment: But I has just moved the Namespace.

Comment: @Sayse Thank you to give me information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without `ref` it's correct

```
public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] destination, int start)
{
    pairs.CopyTo(destination, start);
}
```

It's the caller that has to create the array with the right size, not your method.

Comment: Is array argument is always sent by reference?

Comment: @ChristianIrwanHadiWicaksana No, an array in .NET being a reference type is passed by value. But this isn't a problem because the "original" and the "passed" array are the same array, because they are both references to the real array.

Comment: @ChristianIrwanHadiWicaksana From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx): `A variable of a reference type does not contain its data directly; it contains a reference to its data. When you pass a reference-type parameter by value, it is possible to change the data pointed to by the reference, such as the value of a class member. `